# BSTS different results despite seed argument

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian

I am using the BSTS package for time series forecasting. I define the seed argument, to make the result reproducible

```
bsts(y, state.specification = ss, niter = 1500, ping=100, seed=21)
```

Well at my laptop and also at the laptops of my colleagues the results are the same (and reproducible). Lately, I migrated the code from my i5 windows laptop to a linux server. Now the results are a bit different, but reproducible. 
I looked at the model states, and the sigma related parameters (all generated through MCMC) are slightly different from my laptop computation.

Since the results are reproducible, I assume, that the seed argument is still used, but due to some mystery the results are not the same. 
Just to be sure, I've tried to fix the seed and run

```
runif()
```

et voilà, the server and my laptop both produce the same results. At this point I know, that both the laptop and the server have the same pseudorandom sequence and it is used during the computation. The code is exactly the same but the MCMC runs generate slightly different results.

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Kind regards,
Alex

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue